# Duplicate results when using $.** recursive expression in postgre

Tags: postgresql, jsonpath, timescaledb

I have a timescaleDB, I am trying to make a query using jsonb_path_query but I am getting duplicate results.

Table structure:

```
SELECT * FROM public.meta_table_cum_115
```

```
"time"      "COLUMNNAME"    
"2023-12-22 12:25:31.001244"    "{""1"": [{""results"": {""2"": { ""name"": ""AGE"", ""label"": ""12""}}, ""name"": ""PEOPLE"", ""label"": ""toast""}]}"
```

As you can see there is a nested structure.

I found a mailing at [PostgreSQL Website](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAPpHfdtGcnt8p7pRi6s6qEszqQbQkDjq5pWQGRh_EDExuTW0QA%40mail.gmail.com) about this issue. As I understand it was a bug, but I cannot find a solution anywhere.

When I run a query:

```
select sum(count) as count,label from (select count('label'),
jsonb_path_query(COLUMNNAME, '$.** ? (@.name == "AGE" && @.label!=null)') -> 'label' as label
          
from TABLENAME 
WHERE  TIME BETWEEN to_timestamp(0)  AND to_timestamp(8640000000000)  GROUP BY  label ) as grouped group by label
```

I get result:

```
"count" "label"
1   """12"""
2   """18"""
3   """19"""
1   """31"""
2   """39"""
1   """48"""
```

But when I run this query:

```
select sum(count) as count,label from (select count('label'),
jsonb_path_query(COLUMNNAME, '$.** ? (@.name == "PEOPLE" && @.label!=null)') -> 'label' as label
          
from TABLENAME 
WHERE  TIME BETWEEN to_timestamp(0)  AND to_timestamp(8640000000000)  GROUP BY  label ) as grouped group by label
```

Result:

```
"count" "label"
28  """toast"""
14  """person"""
```

But the actual result is different in the table and must be:

```
"count" "label"
14  """toast"""
7   """person"""
```

Then I deleted one * char from the **$.**** part($.*), it works and results:

```
"count" "label"
14  """toast"""
7   """person"""
```

I don't know what to do now. Do I have to change the way of querying or maybe query differently ($.** or $.*) for nested or non-nested structures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) :

> SQL/JSON path expressions have two modes of handling structural
> errors:
>
> lax (default) — the path engine implicitly adapts the queried data to
> the specified path. Any remaining structural errors are suppressed and
> converted to empty SQL/JSON sequences.
>
> strict — if a structural error occurs, an error is raised.

Also :

> The .** accessor can lead to surprising results when using the lax
> mode. For instance, the following query selects every HR value twice : `lax $.**.HR`

Also :

> To avoid surprising results, we recommend using the .** accessor only
> in the strict mode. The following query selects each HR value just
> once : `strict $.**.HR`

Since the default mode is `lax`, The .** accessor will lead to twice values in your case :

```
select jsonb_path_query(COLUMNNAME, '$.** ? (@.name == "PEOPLE" && @.label!=null)') -> 'label' as label
from meta_table_cum_115
```

Is similar to this :

```
select jsonb_path_query(COLUMNNAME, 'lax $.** ? (@.name == "PEOPLE" && @.label!=null)') -> 'label' as label
from meta_table_cum_115
```

Which for data :

```
create table meta_table_cum_115 (
  time   timestamp,  
  COLUMNNAME  jsonb
);

insert into meta_table_cum_115 values
('2023-12-22 12:25:31.001244', '{"1": [{"results": {"2": { "name": "AGE", "label": "12"}}, "name": "PEOPLE", "label": "toast"}]}');
```

Will returns :

```
label
"toast"
"toast"
```

So to avoid getting duplicates use the strict mode as suggested in the documentation :

```
select jsonb_path_query(COLUMNNAME, 'strict $.** ? (@.name == "PEOPLE" && @.label!=null)') -> 'label' as label
from meta_table_cum_115
```

Will result the correct data :

```
label
"toast"
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/UxGWDQ0q)

Comment: Thank you very much, strict mode perfectly solved my problem